# Python printing text: Highlight or mark some text in the string with indicators

Tags: python, pretty-print

I want to print a string buffer (or byte array) which could contains some special characters, such as \t and \n, besides that, I need to print some indicators below the line to indicate some special part of the string, something like below:

```
a b c d \t , e f g \n 
  ~~~~~~~~   ^^^^^
```

Here is the questions:

1, the escape char  and the normal char should be printed in a fixed width, but I see that repr() function can not.

2, some indicator below the first line should be printed.

3, if we still use repr() function, then I think the marker in the second line should be calculated dynamically, because repr() don't print texts in a fixed width format, thus a `\t` takes two chars.

Any one can help?

BTW: the whole idea is that I want to create a python pretty printer for GDB to show a token when debugging a parsing algorithm.

**EDIT:**
Here is an example:

```
print (repr("abcd\t,efg\n"))
```

when you run the code, you get a printed string which has 12 element instread of 10, for me, ff I want to hight the token "efg", which is the index 6,7,8 in the string, if I draw a markers in the second from the index 6,7,8, I get the following.

```
abcd\t,efg\n
      ~~~
```

Because the "\t" has two chars not the one, which means the function repr() don't print fixed witdh chars, in this case, I would like to see:

```
abcd\t,efg\n
       ~~~
```

Comment: This link may help you: [Print in terminal with colors using Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/287871/print-in-terminal-with-colors-using-python)

Comment: "thus a `\t` takes two chars." -- The alternative is a literal tab, which takes any of 2, 4, or 8 spaces, depending on who's displaying it.  What would you have `repr()` do instead?

Comment: Hi, Kevin, I have make an example to my question